# Convert Wide Matrix to Long Matrix in Python

Tags: python

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

|  | NYC | Georgia | London |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | 0 | 590 | 3200 |
| Georgia | 590 | 0 | 3190 |
| London | 3200 | 3190 | 0 |

I have been trying many things in Python to turn it into a table like this:

| From | To | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | NYC | 0 |
| NYC | Georgia | 590 |
| NYC | London | 3200 |
| Georgia | NYC | 590 |
| Georgia | Georgia | 0 |
| Georgia | London | 3190 |
| London | NYC | 3200 |
| London | Georgia | 3190 |
| London | London | 0 |

Where can I start to solve this? I put in a lot of work just create these tables above.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve]. Tables shown like this are not Python data, and there are multiple ways to represent data like these tables in Python, so you really need to define your problem (input and expected output) in terms of Python data structures (e.g. lists, dictionaries, tuples) for this question to be specific enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: This question will be useful to someone one day. I appreciate your suggestions for formatting my question better however. I have updated the language in the question; hopefully that helps! @PeterWood

Comment: This question will be useful to someone one day. I appreciate your suggestions for formatting my question better however. I have updated the language in the question; hopefully that helps! @kaya3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are dealing with a Pandas DataFrame, then the key is to use [`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```py
>>> df.stack().reset_index().set_axis('From To Distance'.split(), axis=1)
      From       To  Distance
0      NYC      NYC         0
1      NYC  Georgia       590
2      NYC   London      3200
3  Georgia      NYC       590
4  Georgia  Georgia         0
5  Georgia   London      3190
6   London      NYC      3200
7   London  Georgia      3190
8   London   London         0
```

Comment: @Pierre, this worked exactly as I wanted it to!! Thank you very much. I spent 4 hours trying to do that. Thank you very much!!